# Adding submenus to menu tree

Tags: javascript, menu

Can you please help me to add more depth (submenus) to this menu tree? It has only one submenu. The code is in this link: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/dropmenu.htm

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find too many people here willing to fundamentally re-work a JavaScript for you that mentions *IE 4* in its comments :)

I recommend looking for a more modern solution that does what you need out of the box. See for example here: [**38 jQuery And CSS Drop Down Multi Level Menu Solutions**](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/)

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I think this jQuery will solve my problems.
Ahmed.